# How to export comma separated object into a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, time, arduino, pyserial

The below code is meant to output the raw data from the designated serial port to the python shell as well as the amended data now in CSV format ready to output through csv.writer into a .csv file. However the final output is shown as Fri Apr 23 21:30:05 2021 "19,62,0,0,25. As you may be able to observe this is incorrect as the output should be [time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())),decoded_bytes] translating to Fri Apr 23 21:30:05 2021, 19,62,0,0,25. I'm not sure how the ' " ' was added nor why python considers the '19' part of the date-time object and places it in the same column. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import serial
import time
import csv

#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate = 9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-1]
    decoded_bytes = line.replace(":","",5).replace("Soil Moisture","",1).replace("Humidity","",1).replace("CO2","",1).replace("ppm","",1).replace("ppb","",1).replace("%RH","",1).replace("Temp","",1).replace("EC","",1).replace("TVOC","",1).replace(" ","",8)

    if line:  # If it isn't a blank line
        print("Incoming DATA:")
        print(line)
        print(".csv DATA:")
        print(decoded_bytes)
        with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=" ")
            writer.writerow([time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())),decoded_bytes])
```

sample python shell output:

Incoming DATA:
Soil Moisture: 22EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 0ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:25.00

.csv DATA:
22,62.00,0,0,25.00

Incoming DATA:
Soil Moisture: 18EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 400ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:24.45

.csv DATA:
18,62.00,400,0,24.45

Incoming DATA:
Soil Moisture: 15EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 400ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:25.00

.csv DATA:
15,62.00,400,0,25.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adapt this solution, see if it helps.

> file_input.txt

```
Soil Moisture: 22EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 0ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:25.00
Soil Moisture: 18EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 400ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:24.45
Soil Moisture: 15EC, Humidity: 62.00%RH, CO2: 400ppm, TVOC: 0ppb, Temp:25.00
```

> script

```py
import time



import re

def write_to_csv(list_input):
    import csv
    with open('file_output.csv', 'a', newline='') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        wr.writerow(list_input)

def read_input(file_input):
    with open(file_input, 'r') as file_in:
        list_file = file_in.read().splitlines()
        for i in list_file:
            # Find the pattern
            res=re.findall(': ?(\d*\.?\d*)', i)
            # Convert the list to number
            res=list(map(float,res))
            time_stamp = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
            res.insert(0,time_stamp)
            write_to_csv(res)


file_input = 'file_input.txt'
read_input(file_input)
```

> file_output.csv

```
"Fri Apr 23 10:29:11 2021",22.0,62.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
"Fri Apr 23 10:29:11 2021",18.0,62.0,400.0,0.0,24.45
"Fri Apr 23 10:29:11 2021",15.0,62.0,400.0,0.0,25.0
```

Comment: I was able to adapt your solution to get the following output : Fri Apr 23 23:13:32 2021,  [7.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.72]. Now as you can see all the values are in the second column and time is in the first. Thanks for the solution, however your answer doesn't include timestamps and so the data is not able to be graphed with any reference to time.

Comment: That fix works great, the only issue i now have is that it spits out 10 lines or so at a time, if i could get it to only print one line every 2 seconds instead of 10 every 2 seconds i'll mark this as an answer!